# Битрикс не отправляет почту

Tags: битрикс, centos, битрикс24

Лог bitrix/msmtp_default.log выдал ошибку

```
Aug 09 18:52:09 host=mail.--- tls=on auth=on user=---- from=----- recipients=-------- errormsg='the server does not support TLS via the STARTTLS command' exitcode=EX_UNAVAILABLE
```

как исправить - the server does not support TLS via the STARTTLS?

Comment: Попробуйте tls на ssl поменять

Comment: @Talleyran не подскажете в каком файле это можно изменить?

Comment: конфиг лежит в `/home/bitrix/.msmtprc` там все настройки smtp. Только правьте его из под рута и не меняйте права, ато сломается